# How to edit one line in txt file in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to edit the first line in a txt file, but for some reason it will replace the next line with whitespace character...

```
int main()
{
  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
  fprintf(myFile, "Hello\n");
  fclose(myFile);
}
```

txt file before run code:

```
i
like
this
```

txt file after run code:

```
Hello

this
```

Comment: You mean `fprintf(myFile, "Hello\n");` and not `fprintf(file, "Hello\n");`

Answer (score 7):

Your code hasn't replaced lines, it's replaced bytes. Your string ("Hello\n") is six bytes long. The first six bytes of your file are "I\nlike". Once your code has executed you have "Hello\n\nthis" - i.e 'Hello', **two** newlines and 'this'.

If you're trying to replace just the first line you will need to read the entire file, parse it for lines, replace the line you want to replace, then write out the new content.

Comment: What if the file contains millions of  lines?

Comment: Not really any different. If the file has variable length lines you don't know where any given line starts or ends. You could reduce the memory footprint by reading line by line and writing each line as you go, but you still have to read the entire file and write it again.

Comment: @user3408660 If you have a complex use case, describe it in detail in a new question. There are all kinds of tricks, but they depend on the specifics. (Do you have to do this often to the same data? Do you have control over everything that access the file? And so on.)